# Name of array of multidimensional arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, reflection

The name of an array of multidimensional arrays (or a multidimensional array of arrays) in .NET Reflection is in "reverse" order to what you would expect.

For example:

```cs
typeof(int[][,]).Name == "Int32[,][]" // "intuitively" it should be "Int32[][,]"
typeof(int[][,,][,]).Name == "Int32[,][,,][]" // seems it should be "Int32[][,,][,]" instead
typeof(int[][,,][]).Name == "Int32[][,,][]" // this is as I expected, but only because it's symmetrical
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: ...I don't know what you mean by "intuitively".

Comment: I mean that I would expect e.g. typeof(int[][,]).Name to be "Int32[][,]" instead of "Int32[,][]"

Comment: That does seem weird. Consider filing a bug on whatever site Microsoft takes .NET bugs on. This may generate a discussion amongst folks who understand this.

Comment: This is not a multi-dimenensional array, it's a jagged array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a discrepancy between .NET type name system and C# syntax. This array notation makes more sense from the perspective of the type itself, but when you write code it's useful to write arrays differently.

The [article by Eric Lippert](https://ericlippert.com/2009/08/17/arrays-of-arrays/) titled "Arrays of arrays" might be helpful to understand more about array syntax in C# (and array syntax in general).

This answer is based on [the issue I raised](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/92535) in the dotnet/runtime GitHub repository: "Array of multidimensional arrays has wrong name" #92535.